# I need to add a date to a calendar without creating a node

Tags: datetime

I have a difficult use case. I am building a site for a beverage distributor. They want to put their sampling events on a calendar. The problem is the sampling events don't really have a title. They just have the beverage being sampled, the location, and the date/time. Is there a way I can add dates to a calendar without creating a node for them or create a node with no title field?

Comment: The answer obviously depends on *how* you create the calendar. So perhaps you should tell us?

Comment: I'm using the [Calendar Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar).

Comment: To do this using module of your choosing requires a date field (in views' sense of the "field"), so you need to create an entity (easiest - node), or write views-compatible module to display non-entity data. Seems you simply chosen bad tool for this particular task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) module to hide the title field on the form, and automatically populate it with a title. It can work with tokens, so you could configure it to generate node titles like "Event on [node date]".

Comment: There are usually multiple samplings on the same day. Would it be possible to fill the title with something like "Sampling[nid]" or is the nid not issued until the node is actually created? I'm just trying to avoid multiple nodes with the same title.

Comment: Yes, if I'm not mistaken (I last used the module a year ago) you can also use the node id token in your title pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to have to use Nodes then I would dump the Calendar module and use the [FullCalendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar) module. This module can use Views and a Google Calendar to show a calendar on your website on a specific page -- viola no nodes needed. If you need a details page on your site, I recommend a node-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

we can correct this in many ways

1. create nodes manually from code which allow you to add nodes with out titles.
2. remove the default submit handlers and validate functions, which will allow to create empty title nodes.

But the preferred option is to generate a random title, may be a dynamic entry with date and time will be the best option.